# Pass path from spark-submit into Python script

Tags: python, apache-spark

I'd like to pass the path I'm using on my `spark-submit` command line command into my Python script for use when writing out a file. (NOTE: *not* the current working directory, or the full path to the directory where the script itself is located, but the level where the command itself was passed in)

For example:

In the command line:

`spark-submit --imagine_args_here home/new/user/spark.py`

or

`spark-submit --imagine_args_here new/user/spark.py`

And then in my code:

```
import os
dir = path_from_spark-submit.split("/user/spark.py")[0]
with open() as f:
     *write something*
```

This is important to me because I want to be able to run the script from different levels in my directory without it printing to different locations.

Otherwise, is there another way I could achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From `spark-submit -h`:

```
  --conf, -c PROP=VALUE       Arbitrary Spark configuration property.
  --properties-file FILE      Path to a file from which to load extra properties. If not
                              specified, this will look for conf/spark-defaults.conf.
```

You can pass property values using one of these two options.

E.g.
`spark-submit --conf spark.my_arg='new/user/spark.py'`

Then read it using [one of many options](https://kb.databricks.com/data/get-and-set-spark-config.html) you have.

E.g. `path_from_spark_submit = spark.conf.get("spark.my_arg")`